# Can't install R on Ubuntu 20.04 running in WSL 2

Tags: r, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04

So, I am trying to install R on WSL 2 running Ubuntu 20.04. I followed the instructions here [Cran ubuntu packages](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html#supported-packages). As per instructions I added `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/`
 to `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Added the security key `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9`

Ran `sudo apt-get update`. Checked R packages available: `apt list r-base -a`. 
I get this list:

> r-base/bionic-cran40 4.0.1-1.1804.0 all
>
> r-base/bionic-cran40 4.0.0-1.1804.0 all
>
> r-base/bionic 3.4.4-1ubuntu1 all

Finally I ran `sudo apt-get install r-base`. It threw the following error:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.0.1-1.1804.0) but it is not going to be installed
>             Depends: r-recommended (= 4.0.1-1.1804.0) but it is not going to be installed
>             Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed

So I tried running `sudo apt-get install r-base-core`. Got the following error:

```
 r-base-core : Depends: liblapack3 but it is not going to be installed or
                    liblapack.so.3
           Recommends: r-recommended but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: r-base-dev but it is not going to be installed
```

> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Does anyone know why this is happening and if there's a way to install R on WSL 2 Ubuntu? There are other related questions here but they are not for Ubuntu 20.04 and R 4. Your help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You could run R in Jupiter notebooks or through a terminal but I don't think you can use the gui. Install minicondab then use that to install jupyter notebooks, and the ir kernel.

Comment: There are lots of us using those repos, and it works if used as spelled.  Your first paragraph lists `r-base/bionic-cran40 4.0.1-1.1804.0 all` -- you didn't put _that_ in `sources.list` did you?   (And @DAWells no disrect but OP didn;t ask about Conda here.)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I have to say I'm not great with linux. I added `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/` to sources.list and the pakage list from my first paragraph is what I get when I do `apt list r-base`. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: That is correct, but not exactly what you wrote above (or maybe I misread your `apt list` output, sorry). There is a difference between _upgrading_ and _installing a package fresh_. Maybe that plays a role here.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel No it's me. I made a typing error in the older version of my question. Sorry about the confusion. I am doing a fresh install, not an upgrade. I am stumped, I tried different repos on that website I linked, all have the same issue. I wonder if it's because there are different r versions in the output of `apt-list`. I am giving up for now.

Comment: Don't. Maybe subscribe to r-sig-debian and post three, describing your situation in more detail. _Lots_ of people happily use this setup.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you! I will try there

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of those who may have encountered the same issue, I solved it by replacing my original `sources.list` file by the one I got from [this link](https://gist.github.com/ishad0w/788555191c7037e249a439542c53e170). Then I followed the steps found at [the R ubuntu packages page](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html#supported-packages) again and it installed the latest R version (4.0.3) as expected.